# Why noexcept is not enforced at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11

As you might know C++11 has noexcept keyword. Now ugly part about it is this:

> Note that a noexcept specification on a function is not a compile-time
>   check; it is merely a method for a programmer to inform the compiler
>   whether or not a function should throw exceptions.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

So is this a design failure on the committee part or they just left it as an exercise for the compile writers :) in a sense that decent compilers will enforce it, bad ones can still be compliant?

BTW if you ask why there isnt a third option ( aka cant be done) reason is that I can easily think of a (slow) way to check if function can throw or not. Problem is off course if you limit the input to 5 and 7(aka I promise the file wont contain anything beside 5 and 7) and it only throws when you give it 33, but that is not a realistic problem IMHO.

Comment: This explains it I think: http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/

Comment: from what I can see It was hard to do it legit so they did it badly... :( Again Im not bashing them, C++0x was hex already and they needed to get things done, but Im not convinced that safe_sqrt func is brick wall for static analyzers. but good to know that they dont hate me for being a hater :P : "If the noexcept feature appears to you incomplete, prepared in a rush, or in need of improvement, note that all C++ Committee members agree with you. "

Comment: @Pubby put the link as an A, since I have a feeling OP might accept it. :D

Comment: Other than it would be impossible to do so you mean?

Comment: As a note, `noexcept` technically has two different meanings (cannot throw's "no execution path is capable of throwing an exception" and mustn't throw's "program borked if this throws an exception"), and only one of those can technically be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 24):

The committee pretty clearly considered the possibility that code that (attempted to) throw an exception not allowed by an exception specification would be considered ill-formed, and rejected that idea. According to $15.4/11:

> An implementation shall not reject an expression merely because when executed it throws or might throw an exception that the containing function does not allow. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  extern void f() throw(X, Y);
>
>  void g() throw(X) {
>       f(); // OK
>   }
> ```
>
> the call to `f` is well-formed even though when called, `f` might throw exception `Y` that `g` does not allow. —end example ]

Regardless of what prompted the decision, or what else it may have been, it seems pretty clear that this was *not* a result of accident or oversight.

As for *why* this decision was made, at least some goes back to interaction with other new features of C++11, such as move semantics.

Move semantics can make exception safety (especially the strong guarantee) much harder to enforce/provide. When you do copying, if something goes wrong, it's pretty easy to "roll back" the transaction -- destroy any copies you've made, release the memory, and the original remains intact. Only if/when the copy succeeds, you destroy the original.

With move semantics, this is harder -- if you get an exception in the middle of moving things, anything you've already moved needs to be moved *back* to where it was to restore the original to order -- but if the move constructor or move assignment operator can throw, you could get *another* exception in the process of trying to move things back to try to restore the original object.

Combine this with the fact that C++11 can/does generate move constructors and move assignment operators *automatically* for some types (though there is a long list of restrictions). These don't necessarily guarantee against throwing an exception. If you're explicitly writing a move constructor, you almost always want to ensure against it throwing, and that's usually even pretty easy to do (since you're normally "stealing" content, you're typically just copying a few pointers -- easy to do without exceptions). It can get a lot harder in a hurry for template though, even for simple ones like `std:pair`. A pair of something that can be moved with something that needs to be copied becomes difficult to handle well.

That meant, if they'd decided to make `nothrow` (and/or `throw()`) enforced at compile time, some unknown (but probably pretty large) amount of code would have been completely broken -- code that had been working fine for years suddenly wouldn't even compile with the new compiler.

Along with this was the fact that, although they're not deprecated, dynamic exception specifications remain in the language, so they were going to end up enforcing at least some exception specifications at run-time anyway.

So, their choices were:

1. Break a lot of existing code
2. Restrict move semantics so they'd apply to far less code
3. Continue (as in C++03) to enforce exception specifications at run time.

I doubt anybody liked any of these choices, but the third apparently seemed the last bad.

Comment: The primary motivating factor was that doing otherwise would lead to lots of spurious warnings. Often a function can throw but is used in a context where it is known that it will not. The point of `noexcept` was to tell the compiler that you wouldn't throw exceptions -- presumably that's useful because it *can't* tell by itself.

Comment: +1 for the reference. i think maybe Someone(TM) can fill in the details on the decision process. as i recall it was rather hasty thing, following on throwing out modules and PJP stepping down as chair and something.

Comment: Great discussion here: [https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/-PAMYX9dnUQ]. Hm i should have known. ;_)

Comment: That link should be: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/-PAMYX9dnUQ (drop the end bracket).

Comment: Also if you have something like `if(is_prime(googolplex+37)) throw 0;` then what does the compiler do? It cannot evaluate and solve this question. It might be that the function that contains this code is nothrow, but how do we know?? We'd have to solve the halting problem, etc. So, maybe they just wanted the spec not to be impossible, that's some food for thought, isn't it?

Comment: I think the "break a lot of existing code" is the least bad. Most C++ code don't bother with exception specifications anyway. Also in GCC you can use an -std switch to stick to the old standard if it's too expensive for you  to switch. Even if it's not an error it would be still nice to have a warning switch to warn about noexcept violation, you don't want your program to terminate because some functions deep in the call graph is now throwing after an update.

Comment: The problem with "break a lot of existing code", @Calmarius, is that it would've made C++11 all-or-nothing.  If you have to choose between breaking most or all of your code base, or forgoing the new standard entirely, you'd be forced to stick to C++03 until your code is entirely compatible with C++11.  Which, depending on the size and complexity of the code base, could easily be a long time.  In effect, the "break a lot of existing code" option was synonymous with "render the new standard unusable for a lot of users".

Answer (score 11):

One reason is simply that compile-time enforcement of exception specifications (of any flavor) is a pain in the ass. It means that if you add debugging code you may have to rewrite an entire hierarchy of exception specifications, even if the code you added won't throw exceptions. And when you're finished debugging you have to rewrite them again. If you like this kind of busywork you should be programming in Java.

Comment: You would not necessarily "have to rewrite an entire hierarchy of exception specifications", as you can always (just as in Java) `try`/`catch` around the debug code in various shapes and forms -- still a PITA, though to a much lesser extent than your answer claims. :)

Comment: @vladr - um, I said "you **may** have to...".

Answer (score 8):

The problem with compile-time checking: it's not really possible in any useful way.
See the next example:

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& v) noexcept
{
    if (!v.empty())
        ++v.at(0);
}
```

Can this code throw?
Clearly not. Can we check automatically? Not really.
The Java's way of doing things like this is to put the body in a try-catch block, but I don't think it is better than what we have now...

Comment: Actually you could have specified that a noexcept function cannot call a function that might throw (e.g. can only call other noexcepts). Then this could be blocked at compile time because there is a possible execution path that includes `at`, which obviously can throw. Of course, specifying something like this would make noexcept virtually unusable with existing codebases :P.

Comment: Yes, this is what I referred as "Java's way".

Comment: In fact, this code clearly *can* throw. `v` is a reference that could be modified concurrently elsewhere.

Comment: The "Java way" is to admit checked exceptions are a bad idea and use unchecked exception, while the C++ ppl lament about lack of "checked exceptions" in C++. It's just a nice vague notion "I want the compiler to check that at compile time" that makes as much sense as checking for overflow at compile time, that is, none.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand things (admittedly somewhat fuzzy), the entire idea of throw specifications was found to be a nightmare when it actually came time to try to use it in useful way.

Calling functions that don't specify what they throw or do not throw must be considered to potentially throw anything at all!  So the compiler, were it to require that you neither throw nor call anything that might throw anything outside of the specification you're provided actually enforce such a thing, your code could call almost nothing whatsoever, no library in existence would be of any use to you or anyone else trying to make any use of throw specifications.

And since it is impossible for a compiler to tell the difference between "This function may throw an X, but the caller may well be calling it in such a way that it will never throw anything at all" -- one would forever be hamstrung by this language "feature."

So... I believe that the only possibly useful thing to come of it was the idea of saying nothrow - which indicates that it is safe to call from dtors and move and swap and so on, but that you're making a notation that - like const - is more about giving your users an API contract rather than actually making the compiler responsible to tell whether you violate your contract or not (like with most things C/C++ - the intelligence is assumed to be on the part of the programmer, not the nanny-compiler).

Comment: Calling functions that are not specified as `noexcept` and that are in fact `noexcept` is still possible: `try { noexcept_function_that_not_specified_noexcept(); } catch(...) { std::terminate(); /* this will never be called if it's really noexcept */ }`. This expression never throws even if the function inside throws. So this expression is allowed in `noexcept` functions.